# Access Denied. Not Authorized to perform : ec2: DescribeSubnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-policies

When create an EMR cluster, got this error
[image]

The user has the ***ec2: DescribeSubnets*** permission in a policy as below. **What would be root cause?**

```
{
        “Sid”: “AllowOperateClusters”,
        “Effect”: “Allow”,
        “Action”: [
            “elasticmapreduce:RunJobFlow”,
            “elasticmapreduce:DescribeCluster”,
            “elasticmapreduce:ListClusters”,
            “elasticmapreduce:ListBootstrapActions”,
            “elasticmapreduce:ListSteps”,
            “elasticmapreduce:ListInstanceGroups”,
            “elasticmapreduce:OpenEditorInConsole”,
            “elasticmapreduce:ListEditors”,
            “ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes”,
            “ec2:DescribeVpcs”,
            “ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones”,
            “ec2:DescribeSubnets”
        ],
        “Resource”: “*”
    }
```

Comment: If you are sure you do not have any explicit deny in your policies based on tags or anything. Another issue could be from [AWS Service Controlled Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html) if it is denied from SCP.  You might wanna check those as well.

Comment: No explicit deny and the organization is not in use.

Answer (score 1):

It works after granting the below permissions.

```
ec2:DescribeNetworkAcls
ec2:DescribeRouteTables
```